# External iframe change size

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Please take a look at the first video (iframe) [here](http://tv.handball.lv/reportazas/) Is it posible to somehow change width and height so it would look like other videos?

[image]

Comment: You have styled iframe in style.css (line 392) by specifying width and height. Do that in iframe width and height attributes also.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to reposition iframe and hide other parts.

add below CSS to iframe:

```
margin: -60px 0 0 -127px;
width: 500px;
height: 299px;
```

and add **overflow:hidden;** to container div which has **latestPostOtherVideo** class.